# How we protect aws s3 from data corruption

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Actually , I'm trying to safe my s3 bucket data safe.I know AWS S3 is 99.99%  durable.But I want a backup.I have two option one create a snapshot of my existence bucket, but problem is that It's not cost effective.Second option is enable bucket versioning.But It's not holistic approach.Could Please anyone suggest the better and cheaper way to create backup of S3 bucket

Comment: Its actually higher: Designed to provide 99.999999999% durability and 99.99% availability of objects over a given year - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html

Answer (score 3):

It is highly unlikely that you will need to "protect from data corruption". Amazon S3 stores multiple copies of each object (in different data centers!) and uses checksums to ensure that the content has not been corrupted. (Amazon S3 would be more reliable than your backup!)

You might, however, choose to make backups in case somebody *accidentally deletes* an object. Some options are:

- Use versioning to permit objects to be "undeleted" (additional storage costs apply)
- Use cross-region replicas to copy objects to another bucket in another region (requires Versioning to be activated)
- Use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) to download a copy of the objects to your own computer each day using `aws s3 sync`

By the way, it is not possible to "create a snapshot" of an Amazon S3 bucket.

Comment: 1.If i do cross-region replica then cost will be high. 2.if I enable versioning the it's also not cost effective because for one file ,I keep multiple copies. 3.I can't download billions or trillions of files locally.

Comment: If you're worried about cost, then don't take a backup. S3 already keeps multiple copies for you. If you don't trust S3 (even though it's better durability than a normal data center), then you'll need to pay for another copy of your data somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you john for your  fast reply.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein would you add the information of "uses checksums to ensure that the content has not been corrupted." in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: @CloudCho It is referenced in: [Security_Storage_Services_Whitepaper.pdf](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Security/Security_Storage_Services_Whitepaper.pdf)